# How to trigger (notify) a custom event on hardware back key press from native android to web view?

Tags: javascript, android, event-handling, hybrid-mobile-app

How to trigger an event from native android code on hardware back keypress which will notify Webview.

once the event is triggered, I will handle it in javascript like below.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
   //callback
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may get the anwser from the code in cordova

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/4a0a7bc424fae14c9689f4a8a2dc250ae3a47f82/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewImpl.java#L553-L596

here is the docs
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html